# VB.net Findcontrol Not Working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Simple FindControl not working - kicking back:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've got an asp.net label on a web page.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMenuItemName1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

The label control is not inside any other control (datagrid, repeater, etc).  Calling the code on a button click.

```
Dim lblMenuItemName as Label
lblMenuItemName = CType(Page.FindControl("lblMenuItemName1"), Label)
lblMenuItemName.Text = "Hello"
```

I've also tried (and about a half dozen of scenarios):

```
lblMenuItemName = FindControl("lblMenuItemName1")
lblMenuItemName = Me.FindControl("lblMenuItemName1")
```

I'm doing this, instead of referencing the control directly, because I've got ten of these labels and I'm going to assign text through a Loop using

```
FindControll("lblMenuItemName" & x.ToString)
```

FYI - referencing the control directly works fine.

```
 lblMenuItemName1.text = "Hello"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Update:
I've discovered the problem (thanks to comments below) that my problem is that my control is in a Content control.  Now looking to find out how to reference a label within a content control.  Something like:

```
 Dim x As Content = Me.FindControl("Content3")
 Dim lblMenuItemName As Label = x.FindControl("lblMenuItemName1")
 lblMenuItemName.Text = "hello"


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBody" Runat="Server">
<asp:Label ID="lblMenuItemName1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Try doing a recursive find and spitting out the parent where it's found and see if that sheds some light? Also if these are created dynamically they won't be available in a postback, in case that's an unstated part of the problem.

Comment: Can you post your page that would help?

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In putting a sample page together for Zaggler I discovered what I believe to be my problem.  The label control is actually in a Content control:  <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBody" Runat="Server"></asp:Content>  What is is correct way to findcontrol inside the content control?

Comment: See my other comment...I figured this would be the case.

Comment: MrGadget - Wasn't sure what a recursive find was but I'm now assuming that would have revealed it was in a parent control which it is.  Now I'm struggling how to find that control within the parent.  Going to edit question.

Comment: If you search SO for ASP.net FindControl Recursive I'm sure you'll find your answer @user1375002

Answer (score 2):

After several hours and dozens of trial and error, here is what I was looking for:

```
    Dim lblMenuItemName As Label = TryCast(Master.FindControl("ContentBody").FindControl("lblMenuItemName1"), Label)
```